# Calendar Control 12.0 for windows forms application using MsSql database

Tags: winforms, calendar-control

[image: Calendar Control 12.0]

I have a Calendar Control 12.0 in Windows Forms Application. I want to show the jobs allocated for each days with the support of MsSql database. I found some coding about Calendar Control in asp.net. But that same control is not available for Form Application.

Is there any event functions I can use to display the jobs for each days?

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a Calendar control directly to a windows forms is not possible.
But what I did was:

1. Created a web page using asp.net web application and used the calendar control which is available in toolbox for asp.net application. Then I linked the Sql database to show the day to day events.
2. Published the web page and saved the files in a local drive.
3. Then hosted that page locally using IIS.
4. Then in windows forms added a web browser control.
5. Then set the navigation path to the localhost address.

That's all done.

The funny part is for my first question in stack overflow I'm the one providing the answer. :):) After lots of research in internet solved my problem on my own.